# If $f(x) = 0$ has a countable set of solutions, what is $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, terminology

Is there a name given to functions $f$, where the roots of $f(x) = 0$ are countable? I am assuming $f$ is a real function of a real variable, $x$.

Comment: I don't think there's even a name for the case of finitely many roots (remember that $e^x \neq 0$, so it's more than just polynomials even if you're thinking about analytic functions).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the name, but this class of functions all have the form

$$g(x) \chi_{\mathbb{R} \setminus E}(x) $$

where $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ is an arbitrary nonzero function, $E$ is any countable set, and $\chi_F$ is the characteristic function of the set $F$.

In words, you can call these functions "non-vanishing multiples of characteristic (or indicator) functions of a co-countable set".

Answer (score 1):

Many periodic functions have this property. In measure theory a related idea involves a broader definition of negligible sets: "sets of measure zero".

Functions of the kind you are asking about would be a subset of the set of functions which are non-zero "almost everywhere" (used to mean everywhere except a set of measure zero). However, there are uncountable sets of measure zero.

Depending what context you have in mind (and it would be useful to know) this might be the kind of idea you are thinking about.

Comment: For me it came up in a discussion about categorising root finding algorithms by the kinds of functions that it could find all roots of (for a give termination criterion). It seems like this set is the most general set. (I have nothing to back that up at the moment though). The "non-zero almost everywhere" bit seems to be important. Differentiable functions that I can think of that have uncountably many roots only do so because they are zero, e.g., $f(x) \equiv 0$